# Install Bash on Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime+

Tags: installation, bash, samsung-galaxy-grand

How to install Bash on Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime+? How to get root permission and install Bash? Thank in advance !

Comment: Bash can be used without root. Termux provides bash or you can use a static binary. I have built one for my personal use. Rooting is a device specific process, mostly preceded by unlocking bootloader.

Comment: Have a look around at some similar questions, just to understand how Android works and to get to know how it's  changed a bit from Linux... Bash i believe on Android is Shell or /system/bin/sh ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094562/ddg#8095453

Comment: @Zillinium Android's default shell i.e. /system/bin/sh is MirBSD Korn Shell (mksh), not Bash.

Comment: Oh ok... i just looked through the link above and realised the closest alternative is sh .. also rooting Samsung's is annoying .. are you familiar with Knox ?

Comment: Samsung Knox - Better write it correctly https://www.samsungknox.com/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you understand the consequences of tripping Samsung's Knox security flag...

Then please following the rooting guide https://rootsamsung.com/root-samsung-galaxy-grand-prime-plus-sm-g532f

And then use the closest alternative... 
[BusyBox - Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en)

Alternatives are to run a Linux distribution on your  Android and then run a BASH shell through that.
[Linux Apps For Android](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=linux&c=apps&authuser)

Webpage Image for quicker reference of guide @ https://rootsamsung.com/root-samsung-galaxy-grand-prime-plus-sm-g532f

[image: https://rootsamsung.com/root-samsung-galaxy-grand-prime-plus-sm-g532f]